# how to update property of State which is stored in React Context

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i have created  state by using React Context but when i try to update propert of state in child components it do not work, sometime syntax error some time logical error, can anyone please help me ?

---

```
in App.js 
  const [car, setCar] = useState();
  <AuthContext.Provider value={{ car, setCar }}>
      
          <NavigationContainer>
            {car ? (
              <CustomerHomeStackNavigator />
            ) : (
              <Splash></Splash>
            )}
          </NavigationContainer>

      </AuthContext.Provider>
```

---

in child component i want to update its offer property but it not working, i did like this but not worked

```
const carContext = React.createContext();
carContext.setCar.data.offer= "1000"
```

---

car sate have this data object

---

```
 Object {
  "aud": "The_Aud",
  "data": Object {
    "address": "delhi",
    "area": "delhi",
    "city": "delhi",
    "contactnumber": "122222222222",
    "offer": "20000000"
   
  },
  "exp": 1654602892,
  "iat": 1654599292,
  "iss": "The_claim",
  "nbf": 1654599302,
  "stakeHolder": "owner",
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setCar is not object, is a function. you can take value  with `useContext`, can update an object like below

```
const {car,setCar}= useContext(AuthContext);
setCar(prev => {...prev,data : {...prev.data,offer:"10000"}})
```

option 2:

```
var updatedCar = {...car};
updatedCar.data.offer = "1500";
setCar(updatedCar)
```

Comment: awesome, its worked now thanks, i marked it as accepted but due to less score i cant make it green. option 2 worked

Comment: you cannot vote but should be able to as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

`setCar` it is function, so for update you must call function instead of simple
variable assignment.
Next for getting context you must use `useContext` hook or static field `context` if you are going to use class components. You can't use `createContext` for get context value, it is only for create context object.

```
const { car, setCar } = useContext(AuthContext)
// ...
setCar(data)
```

See doc for more details
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#updating-context-from-a-nested-component